# View that displays all rows from tables returned by separate query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to display all rows from multiple tables. The tables to be included are to come from a separate query to ensure. So we know where the data has originated from, a new column must be added that contains the table name.

The tables to be included in this must be dynamic, to reduce maintenance, so newly created tables are automatically included. 
To select the tables I have create this query:

```
select TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'contact_info_type' 
and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%test%' 
and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_STAGING'
```

The testing of the 'contact_info_type' column is to ensure the table is of the expected structure.  All of these tables are exactly the same.

But then how do you pass these results into a new select statement?

I attempts this, which produced duplicate results and would not stop processing. Its also missing the extra column that adds in the table name

```
declare @tableNames nvarchar(max)
select  @tableNames = COALESCE(@tableNames + ', ', '')  + Cast(TABLE_NAME as varchar) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'contact_info_type' and TABLE_NAME not like '%_STAGING' and TABLE_NAME like '%test%'
select @tableNames
declare @sqlText nvarchar(max)
set @sqlText = ''
select @sqlText = @sqlText + 'SELECT * from ' + @tableNames where person = 'Joe'
select @sqlText
```

Each table will contain a few thousand rows but the condition (name = 'Joe') will limit the results to around 100.

Running Server 2008 R2 SP3 (10.50).

Comment: `distinct table_name`?

Comment: you mean to say all table structure will be exactly same.All table that contain column contact_info_type must be included in this query.you need extra column that tell that it belong to which rows.If this the case then this can be done.But in first place what you are trying to do ?what is your real requirement and why are you creating so many tables.

Comment: @KumarHarsh yes all of the tables have exactly the same structure.  This is a 3rd party system that we are working with, it was designed this way. The idea is it uses seperate tables to keep the data isolated. As the results from all of these tables will return in one results set, need to know which table that the results came from, hence a new column that contains the table name that the row belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this query would help you,

But you need to add the additional columns as what you need in your @results table.

```
DECLARE @tables TABLE  (tableName VARCHAR(1000), nmbr INT IDENTITY(1,1))
DECLARE @results TABLE (person varchar(500), tablename varchar(1000))
DECLARE @i INT,
    @tableName varchar(1000),
    @sql varchar(500)

INSERT INTO @tables
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'contact_info_type' 
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%test%' 
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%_STAGING'

SELECT @i = MAX(nmbr)
FROM @tables AS t

WHILE (@i > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT @tableName = tablename
    FROM @tables
    WHERE nmbr = @i

    SET @sql = 'SELECT person, '''+@tablename +''' as tablename
                FROM '+ @tableName +'
                WHERE person = ''joe'''

    INSERT INTO @results
    EXEC (@sql)

    SET @i = @i - 1

END

SELECT * FROM @results
```

Comment: Just had to remove the 'dba_stats.dbo.' in the From and this worked a treat.  Thank you, would have never figured this one out myself

Comment: Oops.. Thanks @oden, I didn't noticed it. I will edit my post now.